# Decomposition of SU(N) adjoint representation under SU(2)

Tags: homework-and-exercises, group-representations

I am having trouble in demonstrating that under SU(2) transformations the adjoint representation of SU(N) transforms as one spin 1, 2(N-2) spin $\frac12$ and singlets. I am trying to demonstrate it from $N \otimes \bar{N} = 1 + A$ where $A$ is the adjoint representation; and the fact that an N vector of SU(N) decomposes as one $j=\frac12$ plus two $j=0$. So basically:
$(1\oplus^{N-2}0)\otimes(1\oplus^{N-2}0)= ?$. But I end up with one spin 1, $2N-3$ spin $\frac12$, and $(N-2)^2+1$ spin 0. Embarrassing. Is my equation with the question mark wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Write things out more carefully.  Under the decomposition $\mathfrak{su}(N) \rightarrow \mathfrak{su}(2)$, you decompose the $\mathfrak{su}(N)$ vector representation into
$$
N \to \tfrac{1}{2} \oplus 0^{\oplus(N-2)}\,.
$$
Then,
$$
N \otimes \bar{N} \rightarrow (\tfrac{1}{2} \oplus 0^{\oplus(N-2)})^{\otimes 2} = 1 \oplus \tfrac{1}{2}^{\oplus(2N-4)} \oplus 0^{\oplus((N-2)^2 + 1)}\,.
$$
That's what you want.  Don't forget that one of those singlets is the singlet in ${\rm Adj} \oplus {\rm Triv}$, since under the reduction $\mathfrak{su}(N) \rightarrow \mathfrak{su}(2)$, ${\rm Triv}$ must reduce to the spin 0 singlet representation.